# How do I make multiple Flux apps talk?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have been creating a `React` calendar.  At first I just wanted to declare the calendar in the `html` with the appointments, like this:

```
<Calendar appts={appts} />
```

But then I realized that my calendar was going to have to be a full app, talking to the `REST` endpoints and have it's own `store` and `actions`.

The calendar was not the end goal, and now I need it to be part of a bigger 'Flux' app.  How is everyone architecting their apps, so that the pieces can be reused, say the calendar, in other apps?  How do the different `Flux` apps talk to each other?  Are there any examples or blog posts where this is talked about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux is an [publisher-subscriber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) architecture recommendation from Facebook.  **RefluxJS** is an easy to use implementation of this architecture.  It adds `actions` and `stores` to ReactJS.

Actions are triggers for change.  Whenever the user interacts with the page you call an action.  Actions have almost completely replaced setState inside a React component for me.  When a user creates an event such as a form field change, I fire an action with the event data as a function parameter.  In this architecture, actions allow React components (classes) to broadcast publish changes.

Stores subscribe (listen) to actions.  The simplest store simply passes on parameters that have changed with a `this.trigger` call.  Other stores may listen to other stores, validate data, stuff parameters into data, set data into an object, or push data onto an array than broadcast the new dataset with a `this.trigger` call.

React components (classes) and stores can subscribe (listen) to stores.  When these stores update, you can

- Update state and all dependent props
- Do something with the updated store dataset

Reflux comes with a very useful `connect` mixin which allows you to link the state of a class to a store.  Be careful though, be sure to implement getInitialState in the store if you do this.  Otherwise, your class will start with a null state. Another useful mixin is the `ListenerMixin` if you just want the component to do something when a store changes.

For more information, be sure to checkout the [RefluxJS README](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs).